# Can I disable powerpoint from using the complete screen in presentation mode?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I use a projector to display to a whiteboard. I would like to use powerpoint with a word file displayed by the side. Powerpoint utilises the complete screen as soon as i choose display from current slide. Is there a method of getting powerpoint to use 1/2 screen?

Comment: http://busynessgirl.com/how-to-run-a-powerpoint-not-in-full-screen/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. It would also be helpful to know what version you are using. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using PowerPoint 2013. Under the Slide Show tab, click the Set Up Slide Show button. Under show type, click "browsed by an individual (window)." When you present, there will be a window that you can drag and resize however you want.

Comment: Yes.  And the same "browsed by an individual" setting works in all versions of PPT back into the mists of long-forgotten time.